# Iterate through nested JSON list and add one value to a list

Tags: json, list, loops, dictionary, key-value

I have a bunch of JSON data that I need to extract one value from. Unfortunately it's rather deeply nested and I can't figure out a way to pull the specific values out that I need. Here's a sample of the data:

```
{
  "123abc" : {
    "g" : "9v6mp",
    "l" : [ 25.412088115916596, -99.7504587164702 ]
  },
  "456abc" : {
    "g" : "9v6kn",
    "l" : [ 25.24162649903667, -99.78022809032183 ]
  },
  "789abc" : {
    "g" : "9vffq",
    "l" : [ 27.75048435345363, -99.0829715511575 ]
  }
}
```

I need to pull just the "l" value into a list.

I've tried:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open ("daydreamer-b8036-all-export (1).json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
locationList = []
for key in data:
        value = data["l"]
        locationList.append(value)
print(locationList)
```

which doesn't work and throws an error. If I change the "l" in the for loop to something unspecified I just get the whole nested portion, not just the "l" value.

I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious but I have very little experience working with nested JSON and am really struggling! Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using:

```
for key in data:
        value = data[key]
        for k in value:
            location = value["l"]
            locationList.append(location)
print(locationList)
```